# How to construct android AttributedString for api level 11

Tags: android, string, android-layout

I know how to do this in iOS but not yet in [android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/AttributedString.html). How do I construct an attributed string in android where a portion is bold as in

"this is the example with a **bold portion**"

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I have never seen `AttributedString` used, in ~6.5 years of Android development work.

A class implementing `Spanned` contains markup rules ("spans"). The simplest way to construct one dynamically is by using `Html.fromHtml()` to parse an HTML string with basic tags like `<b>`. String resources (e.g., `res/values/strings.xml`) also support `<b>`, `<i>`, and `<u>` tags.

Or, you can apply spans yourself. In the sample code that follows, I get the `CharSequence` from a `TextView`, remove all existing spans, and highlight search terms with a `BackgroundColorSpan`:

```
  private void searchFor(String text) {
    TextView prose=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.prose);
    Spannable raw=new SpannableString(prose.getText());
    BackgroundColorSpan[] spans=raw.getSpans(0,
                                             raw.length(),
                                             BackgroundColorSpan.class);

    for (BackgroundColorSpan span : spans) {
      raw.removeSpan(span);
    }

    int index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text);

    while (index >= 0) {
      raw.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF8B008B), index, index
          + text.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      index=TextUtils.indexOf(raw, text, index + text.length());
    }

    prose.setText(raw);
  }
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/RichText/Search))

For boldface or italics, you would use `StyleSpan` instead of `BackgroundColorSpan`, and so forth.